# How do I turn off auto-complete for Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

As I am typing in Code::Blocks, I would prefer to type code directly without having the editor insert closing parentheses and brackets.

I chose the disable code-completion in Settings > Editor > Code Completion, but this feature does not disable auto complete features with closing characters.

What is the right setting for turning off this feature in Code::Blocks?

(Be aware this could happen to you by the pronoun censors: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/08/stack_overflow_apology/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Settings -> Editor... -> General settings -> Indent options -> Brace completion"

Answer (score 1):

I got it,How to disable the auto brace and etc.....**Tools**>**Editor** **option**>**Completion**....you will find two tabs under the main tab **Code** **completion** and **Symbol** **completion**....Disable both tick marks of it and free to write coding....

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to:

"Settings -> Editor X -> General Settings -> Indent options -> Complete brackets"

And with that, it would have to work

Answer (score 0):

`Tool=>Editor Options=>Completion tab=>symbol completion`

Unselect the ones that are not desirable