# How to fix "The parser is still parsing files" popup in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

So I have not changed any settings in my code blocks editor and yet this appears I am new to the code blocks editor and if anyone could explain how this could popup so I can fix it and I have heard people will disable code completion to fix this but I never had the problem with it on so

I have tried disabling code completion this did fix the problem but it normally wouldn't do this with code completion on and I don't want it off

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737883/turn-off-auto-complete-for-codeblocks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off auto-complete for Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737883/turn-off-auto-complete-for-codeblocks)

Comment: here, have some punctuation marks, they are free, no strings attached: `,,,,,,,,.....?`. Now please use them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that rebooting the program has fixed this problem... Also I uninstalled the Library finder which I had opened once by accident then closed the program not saving and changes to anything which then restored library finder and apparently fixed the issue...

Answer (score 10):

1. Open Code Blocks settings screen
2. Click "Editor..."
3. On the left, scroll down and choose "Code completion"
4. Choose "C/C++ Parser"
5. Make sure the checkmark on "Use one parser for the whole workspace" is checked

Then after saving the changes restart your Code Blocks IDE and make project save it. After that your issue is resolved.

[image: Codeblocks screenshot]

Comment: Just to say that I tested this solution and it worked. Should be the accepted solution instead of the current one.

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions mentioned above helped me!
I found myself solution, try whether it works for you not!

Settings -> Editor... -> scroll down (tabs on the left) -> Code Completion -> C/C++ parser -> Use one parser per project (check this option) -> Reduce "Maximum allowed parsers". Mine worked when I kept it to 2.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: 
Create two C/C++ files. Build and run them. Go to the C/C++ file you've built first and try to write something. Now, your issue should be fixed.
There's a youtube video explaining this trick. You can watch this if you face any difficulty: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sduqmX_VXB8

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Save the file declaring which type it is. If C++, save it as *whatever.**cpp*** and it's gonna work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your file name should start with lower case alphabet.

Answer (score -1):

We have to simply do one thing i.e. stop the code completion.

Goto "Settings" menu --> "Editor" --> "General Settings" (Left Pallet) --> "Editor settings" tab --> uncheck the "Code completion" checkbox..

Save the setting and you are good to go.. now u will never get that pop-up again..